# How to install r package locally using devtools::install_local

Tags: r, package, devtools

I have the following R packages:

```
ubuntu@ip-111-31-16-140:~/storage1/homebrew_rpackages/mypackr$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/storage1/homebrew_rpackages/mypackr
```

The structure is:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-140:~/storage1/homebrew_rpackages/mypackr$ tree
.
|-- DESCRIPTION
|-- NAMESPACE
|-- R
|   |-- hello.R
|   `-- tsne_pca.R
|-- mypackr.Rproj
`-- man
    |-- hello.Rd
    `-- plot_tsne_pca.Rd
```

What I tried to do is to install locally this way, but gives error:

```
> devtools::install_local("/home/ubuntu/storage1/homebrew_rpackages/mypackr")
Installation failed: trying to get slot "name" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do at least one commit in your git repository of your package.

Comment: @chade_ I've changed the text. Maybe you can see now that it is an answer.